# Refer to directory in another Gradle sub-project

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build with sub-projects. Until recently, one of the sub-projects needed a reference to the `libraries` sub-directory within it's own `build` directory. I achieved this as follows:

```
file("${buildDir}/libraries")
```

I now need to change that reference to pick the `build` directory from another sub-project (called `gui`). I can't find a way to use the Gradle DSL to achieve this. Instead I have it expressed as follows:

```
new File(project(':gui').buildDir, 'libraries')
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in Gradle?

Comment: file("${rootProject.project('gui').buildDir}/libraries")

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti.  That certainly looks better to me than what I originally had.  If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine Gradle DSL with Groovy [String interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation), and write your statement as follows

```
file("${rootProject.project('gui').buildDir}/libraries")
```